# Get hardware Info

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, .net-2.0, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

How to get hardware information of a system using c# code?

Comment: Can you specify what hardware information you are seeking?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the System.Management namespace for retrieving the hardware information of a machine using C#.

[Here's an article for retrieving hardware information in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/hardware_properties_c_.aspx).

And [here's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394554(VS.85).aspx) a list of [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582(VS.85).aspx) classes.