# Getting PC Hardware Serial Numbers

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0

I'm building an application for my personal use, in which I need to get the Serial Number of the hardware of the PC. i.e.: Motherboard, RAM(s), HDD(s), Cards, and any other device installed.

I've searched around the internet but couldn't find anything working with me!!

I'm using WPF on C#, and .NET Framework 4.0

I've just finished a preliminary design.

Comment: does this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/908902/get-hardware-info?

Comment: This doesn't give me the Serial Number of the devices installed in the PC! .. I need to have the Serial Numbers ...

Comment: this is WMI - you can get everything about hardware you want to know, just tinker with appropriate WMI classes. Here is the list of all WMI classes - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17973/How-To-Get-Hardware-Information-CPU-ID-MainBoard-I